# gsutil ls returns error: "contains wildcard"

Tags: gsutil

For some reason, we've got a folder which causes `gsutil ls` to error:

```
$ gsutil ls -lR gs://mybucket/proj103

...
...
...
gs://mybucket/proj103/delivery/161025_To_Viewport/app_icon/:
  39219977  2016-11-17T10:44:08Z  gs://mybucket/proj103/delivery/161025_To_Viewport/app_icon/App Ikon.psd
CommandException: Cloud folder gs://mybucket/proj103/delivery/161025_To_Viewport/app_icon/Client - VR [Squared]/ contains a wildcard; gsutil does not currently support objects with wildcards in their name.
```

When I look in the network share (from my Windows machine) from which the files originate (we upload them to the bucket nightly vi `gsutil rsync`) I see this:

```
    Directory: \\10.1.1.100\prod\proj103\delivery\161025_To_Viewport\app_icon


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----       10/25/2016   6:18 PM                Client - VR [Squared]
-a----       10/25/2016   5:29 PM       39219977 App Ikon.psd
```

Are those brackets causing some kind of issue?

I'm on gsutil version 4.22.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is: yes, unfortunately the brackets are what's causing the issue here.

This is a current limitation in gsutil, and it's being tracked in a GitHub issue [(#290)](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/290). I've added a reference to your Stack Overflow post there.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answer by @mhouglum (thanks!) I'd like to add that there's a workaround:

```
gsutil ls -lR gs://mybucket/proj103/**
```

This workaround was suggested, also by @mhouglum, [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/290#issuecomment-279893108).